# Unique list from hasMany association ManyArray in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a collection of `Elks`:

```
App.Elk = DS.Model.extend(
  family:      DS.belongsTo('family')
  friends:     DS.hasMany('friends')
)
```

In my `Elks` `ArrayController`, I want to get a list of all unique families and friends based on my list of `Elks`. I can do this with `family` easily, because it is a one-to-one relationship:

```
App.ElksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
  family: Ember.computed.uniq('@each.family')
)
```

I tried `Ember.computed.uniq('@each.friends.@each')` but `@each` only works one level deep, and Ember doesn't seem to have a `flattenArray` function.

Is there a clean way to do this with a `hasMany`?